# GCP Run Jobs, Receiving a Random Interuption

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I set up a GCP Run Job to execute a Rails Runner command. Before things finish I am receiving a random interupt message:

E0221 20:50:02.307257047      54 ev_epoll1_linux.cc:1142]              ASSERTION FAILED: next_worker->state == KICKED

Anyone know what this message could mean or how to prevent the interrupt?

Best,

Answer (score 0):

My docker image is running rails, my workaround was to set the following environment variables:

GRPC_POLL_STRATEGY=poll
DISABLE_SPRING=true

Hope this saves someone some time.